# Calling sleep on current thread stalls my main GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, multithreading, halt

I have one class `DataThread` inherited from Thread.
I am using two `DataThread` objects `ReadThread` and `WriteThread`.
I have another thread where `Main_GUI` is running.

Now when I press a button on `main_GUI` it calls a method `x.method1()` and then this method uses the WriteThread method WriteThread.sleepForReset(). In

```
public void sleepForReset(){
    try {
        sleep(28000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I press the button on `main_GUI` the GUI stalls for `28000` miliseconds.
If I am calling sleep on `WriteThread` then why it halts the `main_GUI`?
Is it because the sleep is a static method? If yes can anybody suggest how to sleep the `WriteThread` without affecting `Main_GUI`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks all of you for suggesting me different options.....
But I used TimeTask.schedule() and worked. I scheduled my job for later instead of using sleep in the current thread......

Answer (score 6):

If you are calling `WriteThread.sleepForReset()` from within your `actionPerformed` method, you are actually calling it from within the EventDispatch Thread.  Even though you have an object that represents your WriteThread, calling a method on that object from within the EventDispatch Thread will cause the process to be performed within the EDT.

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) on using worker threads in Java.  Note that it isnt enough to just have a class that inherits from `Thread`, you need to have the instances of these Threads to be started for you to have a multithreaded app.  The tutorial provided will give you a good idea on one way to get started.

Answer (score 1):

I think calling people Geeks is not necessarily a good way to get help, but to answer your question, you're seeing the sleep because you're calling Thread.sleep on the event dispatch thread. Swing's GUI operations run on this single thread. If you need to do long running background work, you should delegate it to a SwingWorker.

Also, the handling of interrupted exception is not very robust. At the very least, you should be reinterrupting the thread with Thread.currentThread().interrupt().

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.......
I will never ever call anybody "Geek" in my life...   
But what I can do ? I am desperate for help...   :)